# Python - Manage imports in VSC

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, import

How do I properly import in python. I now the concept of importing out of java with an ide. If I code in Python, I use Visual Studio Code. My Problem was: How can I enable some sort of "auto-import" feature.

If there is no such feature how to I import things. In witch order and with how many spaces/returns in between?

Programm I am using: Visual Studio Code.

Comment: I think your question is not related to a specific IDE. You need to understand how 'import' works in python. You can read here https://www.codementor.io/sheena/python-path-virtualenv-import-for-beginners-du107r3o1

Answer (score -1):

python includes the .py extension for execution its program. it works on direct compiling process thus this is known as interpreted language . For the proper work in python u must know about python

Comment: This does not answer the question at all